# ~/.bash_profile being executed for non-login shells

Tags: bash, shell, login, bashrc

My bash_profile looks like:

```
takeapic
#print status
#do other stuff
source ~/.bashrc
```

For some reason, every terminal emulator I call executes this script. Shouldn't it be executed only once, when I login. Why is this happening?

My bashrc contains these commands:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/saga/bin
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR=vim
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33'

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -a'
alias lla='ls -al'
alias cx='chmod +x'
alias clipboard='xsel -b'
alias diff='diff --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias sakura='sakura -e tmux'
alias zathura='zathura --fork'

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredupd
```

I understand tmux starts every pane as a login shell, but sakura executes .bash_profile even when I call it by it's path.

Comment: Most of the terminal emulators do login.

Comment: I use sakura as terminal emulator. It's man page says it should be given '-l' while calling it for it to behave as a login shell.